# Grand Central Dispatch, Dispatch WorkItem Flags

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

Which one of:

```
 public static let barrier: DispatchWorkItemFlags
 public static let detached: DispatchWorkItemFlags
 public static let assignCurrentContext: DispatchWorkItemFlags
 public static let noQoS: DispatchWorkItemFlags
 public static let inheritQoS: DispatchWorkItemFlags
 public static let enforceQoS: DispatchWorkItemFlags
```

is default DispatchWorkItemFlag?

Answer (score 2):

Each of these options has its own meaning and there is no one default option.

So, you're probably asking what is default parameter for  [`init(qos:flags:block:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchworkitem/2300102-init) (item’s property) of `DispatchWorkItem` or its [`notify(qos:flags:queue:execute:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchworkitem/2016099-notify) method.

So, regarding to docs, default parameter is empty `OptionSet`.

Comment: @Thanks, I saw this just now!

Answer (score 1):

**Quick answer: All of them, none of them.**

DispatchWorkItemFlags **are an option set that configure the behavior of a DispatchWorkItem value**, including its quality of service class and whether to create a barrier or spawn a new detached thread.

When you add a job into the queue, DispatchWorkItemFlags gives us several options to choose:

```
public func sync<T>(flags: DispatchWorkItemFlags, execute work: () throws -> T) 

    rethrows -> T

public static let barrier: DispatchWorkItemFlags
public static let detached: DispatchWorkItemFlags
public static let assignCurrentContext: DispatchWorkItemFlags
```

> DISPATCH_BLOCK_ASSIGN_CURRENT Indicates that a dispatch block should
>   be assigned the execution context attributes that are current at the
>   time the block object is created. …
>
> DISPATCH_BLOCK_BARRIER Indicates that a dispatch block should act as a
>   barrier block when submitted to a DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT queue. …
>
> DISPATCH_BLOCK_DETACHED Indicates that a dispatch block should execute
>   disassociated from current execution context attributes such as QoS
>   class, os_activity_t, and properties of the current IPC request, if
>   any. …

I hope it helped!

You have a very nice day!

Answer (score 1):

As usual answer is in documentation :)

init(qos: DispatchQoS = .unspecified, flags: DispatchWorkItemFlags = [], block: @escaping () -> Void)

Comment: So default value is empty set, thanks to Aleksandar Vacic